# Python parse only specific parts of text file

Tags: python, parsing, readfile, extract

I have a text file containing lots of data that looks something like this:

```
logstart . . .
(chunk of data)
logend . . .
logstart . . .
(chunk of data)
logend . . .
times
logstart . . .
(chunk of data)
logend . . .
times
logstart . . .
(chunk of data)
logend . . .
```

I want my Python code to open the file and read the chunks of data if and only if there are "times" associated with it right below its "logend". If there are no times for that chunk I want it to ignore it. And when it reads the correct chunks of data I also want it to read the times associated with it.

This is what I had before I realized I needed to extract only those certain parts (which saved the entire text file as 'lines'):

```
lines = []
with open(filename, 'rt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        lines.append(line)
```

How can I change this so that 'lines' are now just those specific parts of the file?

Comment: Using regex seems indicated, together with `re.findall`.

Comment: Please post more information.  A sample of a log chunk, along with what you would like to capture would help.

Comment: I'm using regex to extract the specific data that I need within the chunks of data (since I only need some of it). But my current issue is getting it to only apply the rest of my code to the data for the specific parts of the file that has "times" associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
lines = []
with open(filename, 'rt') as in_file:
    chunk = []
    for line in in_file:
        chunk.append(line)
        if(line.find('times')>=0):
            lines.extend(chunk)
        if(line.find('logstart')>=0):
            chunk = []
```

Comment: This solution also includes the `times`, `logstart` and `logend` lines. OP was not clear on whether they wanted that.

Comment: Also, you need to use `True` and `False`.

Comment: Yes it's fine if it includes those lines because I'm doing regex later anyway. However this solution isn't working for me -- I'm getting an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Sorry, get my languages mixed up now and then.  I fixed it.

Comment: @lancew thank you! That helps a lot. However when the code picks out the "times" I need the corresponding chunk of data that it extracts to be the one immediately preceding that time, but when I run it it's picking out the chunk of data below. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've changed my post, try now.

Comment: @WynneT did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by keeping track of a little state.

```
lines = []
with open(filename, 'rt') as in_file:
    in_log = False
    save = []
    for line in in_file:
        if 'logend' in line:
            in_log = False
        if in_log:
            save.append(line)
        if 'times' in line:
            save.append(line)
            lines.extend(save)
        elif 'logstart' in line:
            in_log = True
            save = []
```

Comment: Thanks, although a couple issues I'm facing -- I think this code is picking out the chunks of data that are below the "times", but I want only the ones that are above wherever there are "times". I'd also like the "times" themselves to be shown too.

Comment: @WynneT Updated answer based on your feedback.